# How can i hyperlink in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYxO5.png)Im trying to link to another site but it is not working

`WOW, the ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME} is yours! go visit ${<a href={`http://google.com`}>Google</a>} to view it.`

Comment: updated answer in first answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Tags (multiple childs) in it, you cannot use like:

```
`WOW, the ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME} is yours! go visit <a href="http://google.com">Google</a> to view it.`
```

You have to use **React.Fragment**:

```
<React.Fragment>
      WOW, the ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME} is yours! go visit <a href="http://google.com">Google</a> to view it.
</React.Fragment>
```

**React.Fragment:**
A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: still doesnt work , just added a picture of how the code looks like

Comment: Can you add code instead picture

Comment: this update `WOW, the ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME} is yours! go visit <a href="http://google.com">Google</a> to view it.` didnt work

Comment: @ivanjimenez, answer updated with **React.Fragment**

Comment: it worked!! how can i change the color ?